# wrong result of casting string to int C++

Tags: c++

```
string test;
test="3527523";
int a=test[3];
std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
```

I was expecting output to be number 7, but I got 55 instead.
I have searched through different posts, they all used this method without any problems.. I just don't know where the problem is in my case.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could try this: [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: the value of test[3] is '7' not 7. the ascii character '7' evaluates to 55. see http://www.cpptutor.com/imgs/ascii_table.gif

Comment: Instead of `int a = test[3]` try this: `int a = test[3] - '0'`. That should print `7`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`test[3]` returns `char`, which you're converting to an integer, so it returns the ASCII value of the character. `3` in ASCII is `55`.

Try using `char` instead as the type of `a`:

```
char a = test[3];

std::cout << a; // 3
```

If you wanted the result to be an integer, subtract the character from `'0'`:

```
std::string test = "3527523";

int a = test[3] - '0';

std::cout << a; // 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I know I asked a really stupid question
So what does '0' really do in here to make it a correct ans?

Comment: user2341380, If you consult a table of ASCII values, the values for `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`... are 48, 49, 50, 51... so when you subtract 51 (`'3'`) from 48 (`'0'`) you get 3. Works for all ASCII digits.

Comment: `'0'` is a character literal and has the ASCII value of 48. When arithmetic is applied to at least one operand of type `char`, integral promotion is applied. That means `'0'` is converted to 48. The values of the characters from `'0'` to `'9'` are 48 to 53 (do you get it now) :)?

Comment: @user2341380 Let's say we wanted to convert the character `'1'` to an integer. `'1'` has the ASCII value `49`. Subtracting from `'0'` (48) gives the integer `1` (49 - 48 == 0).

Comment: @user2341380 Sorry, I meant (49 - 48 == 1).

Answer (score 0):

You get the char '7' by the brackets, which has the ASCII code 55 (48+7).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you assign `test[3]` to a variable of type `int`, thus causing the actual character code (55) to be printed instead of the represented character (`'7'`). Replace `int` with `char` or `static_cast` before printing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "cast", you "convert".

You can use sscanf(), atoi() among other functions to convert the value of a string:

`int iret = sscanf (test, "%d", &a);`

The value of test[3] is the ASCII character '7', which is actually the integer "55".

PS:
The beauty of "sscanf()" is that you can easily detect if a parse error occurred by checking for "iret != 1".

Answer (score 0):

Use atoi:

int atoi (const char * str); //Convert string to integer

For example:

```
string test;
test="3527523";
const char c = test[3];
int a=atoi(&c);
std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
```

Comment: `i` will then be equal to the number 3527523. That's not what he wanted.

Comment: Requires a C-string.  Plus, that won't get the value of one digit, as the OP's code shows an attempt to do.