# How to make a switch statement with a vector string?

Tags: c++, vector, switch-statement, console-application

```
vector<string> cmdV = split(_cmd, " ");

switch (cmdV[0])
{

}
```

For some reason it gives me the error: "The value must have an integral or enum type" in cmdV[0]

Comment: The message says it all, really. You can't.

Comment: Use a chain of `if`s. Or, if you feel fancy, a `std::map` (or other container) of lambdas.

Comment: `switch` only takes numeric types, use `if` `else if`, or a `std::unordered_map<string,std::functionv<void ()>>` instead.

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience and thank you very much for clarifying the switch statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to make a switch statement with values from a `vector<string>` you can use either `atoi()` or `std::stoi()`. More described in this answer: [How can I convert a std::string to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/how-can-i-convert-a-stdstring-to-int).

The following code should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> test;

    test.push_back("2");

    switch(std::stoi(test[0])) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "IT WORKS!";
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "IT WORKS 2!";
            break;     
    }
}
```

It should print `"IT WORKS 2!"` without errors.

Or if you would want a string such as `std::string str = "Test"` to be one of the cases you could use the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-the-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings) previous question:

> ```
> enum string_code {
>     eFred,
>     eBarney,
>     eWilma,
>     eBetty,
>     ...
> };
>
> string_code hashit (std::string const& inString) {
>     if (inString == "Fred") return eFred;
>     if (inString == "Barney") return eBarney;
>     ...
> }
>
> void foo() {
>     switch (hashit(stringValue)) {
>     case eFred:
>         ...
>     case eBarney:
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

**NOTE:** You should read a bit and make sure you understand the errors that might occur if you do this. And also read about different data types or else errors like this might occur: [wrong result of casting string to int C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492463/wrong-result-of-casting-string-to-int-c)

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comment below by [@theOtherMichael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14720883/theothermichael) the code above is not a "real" hashing method. But as found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-the-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings) post there is a way to use the same idea but actually hash the values.

> ```
> constexpr unsigned int hash(const char *s, int off = 0) {                        
>     return !s[off] ? 5381 : (hash(s, off+1)*33) ^ s[off];                           
> }                                                                                
>
> switch( hash(str) ){
>     case hash("one") : // do something
>     case hash("two") : // do something
> }
> ```

What can happen here though is that different strings might return the same value but it should work.

Comment: Since this question is a frequent one for beginners, I feel it's important to clarify that in the code example above, `hashit()` is _not actually_ a hash function, but a stand-in for one.  If you want to hash a string for use in a `switch` statement, you will need to replace `hashit()` with an actual hashing algorithm: otherwise, you may as well write `if` statements.

Comment: @theOtherMichael I added another answer from the same post which should also work!

Answer (score 2):

`switch` statements require integral types on both the condition and the `case` statements (the latter of which must be known at compile-time).  If you're making conditions based on the contents of a string, you must use something else, such as an `if` statement.

If you have to do a lot of conditional programming based on your strings, you might consider hashing your strings into integers.  If done right, this can allow you to use switch statements in a switch faster than full string compares can be done.  I made a [compile-time version of the SpookyHash algorithm](https://github.com/theOtherMichael/CTSpookyHash) for this exact purpose.